# Real-time display of results in Python

Tags: python, plot, real-time

I have this program which will solve a system of differential equations in such way that two values xi, yi are produced each time a for loop iterates. Is there some way i could plot these values as they are produced instead of waiting for the computation to finish, then plotting them all?

Comment: Think about how you would print out the value calculated at each iteration. The program will print out to console the results of the current iteration when it reaches the line telling it to. Apply this logic to a 2d graph you are displaying. All you need to do is to update the graph at the end of each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at matplotlib (http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) or gnuplot.py (http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/). I've used these to plot data after I was done, but I don't see a reason why you could not do this while you are generating the data. However, depending on how fast your loop executes, chances are this will slow down your whole program.

The gnuplot may not be maintained any longer, but I have been using it w/o any problems.

Comment: I have used those before, but as you say, only to plot already-calculated values. It would be ideal that if the point-calculation goes faster than the display update, it would show only some of the calculated points

Comment: One approach, you could code your loop (using e.g., the mod operator) only to plot every nth data set. I.e., rather than plotting every value, just sample a subset of your data as you generate them.

Comment: e.g., to plot every fifth value inside your loop maintain a counter (e.g., count) that you increment each time through the loop. Then have something like: if not count%5: plot_values(xi, yi)

Comment: The problem with that, is that it will fill my screen with lots of plot windows (for the applications I know of)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your algorithm looks like this:

```
import matplotlib

x_list = []
y_list = []
while True:
    xi, yi = compute() # calculates your xi and yi value
    if converged(xi, yi):
        break
    # capture history of your xi and yi
    x_list.append(xi)
    y_list.append(yi)

matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x, y) # create a graph representing x and y
```

Comment: That would make the plot AFTER the calculation. What I need is to plot a point each time it's caculated. (Like having the last line indented, but that's messy)